# Can to login to WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I am new to WordPress site development. I have a problem with a WordPress site. The problem is if i logout once i can not login again to the site. The login page shows blank.

I don't know why this happening and how to fix this.

Badly need solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your functions.php file.Is there any blank whitespace at the end of page?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: No. actually i am very poor in php. Can you please tell me what should i check in error log? @bear

Comment: Did you modify CORE files?

Comment: @Blackboy ask your host.

Comment: No. i did not modify anything. My client give me to fix this. @jQuery Angry Bird

Comment: Add this code to your wp-config.php file:
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);

And then see what error messages are output.

Comment: Around 12 error message is in error_log.
All are almost same with different file name. Below is the example. 

[11-Nov-2014 20:14:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/changeor/public_html/wp-content/themes/buzz/library/widgets/widget-facebook-fans.php:119) in /home/changeor/public_html/wp-login.php on line 418